# Drawing the phase portrait of an autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have to draw the phase portrait of this ODE:

$$\ddot{x} = -x (x - 1) (x + 2)$$

Since this ODE is an autonomous equation I know that it can be represented as:

\begin{align}
  \dot{x} &= y\\
  \dot{y} &= -x (x - 1) (x + 2), (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2
\end{align}

For this specific system, the nullclines are given by:

$$\dot{x}=0 \rightarrow y = 0$$

$$\dot{y}=0 \rightarrow x=0, x=1, x=-2$$

We can see that $\dot{y}$ changes sign at each of the equilibrium points. Specifically, it is positive for $x<-2$, negative for $-2<x<0$, positive for $0<x<1$, and negative for $x>1$. This means that in the $x$-$y$ phase plane, $y$ will increase  when $x<-2$ or $0<x<1$, and $y$ will decrease when $-2<x<0$ or $x>1$. I don't know how to proceed from here, what should I do?

Comment: Maybe identify the equilibria (steady states) and find their stability?

Comment: Hmmm, how Do I find the steady states? Through the Jacobian of $[\dot{x}, \dot{y}]$? I know that i can finde about their stability analysing the behavior of $\dot{x}, \dot{y}$ in the space, right?

Comment: @Moo, what answer?

Comment: @Moo, I see it now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the critical points where $x' = y' = 0$ simultaneously

$$(x, y) = (-2, 0), (0,0),(1,0)$$

Find the Jacobian of your matrix

$$\mbox{jac}(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
 -3 x^2-2 x+2 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Evaluate the eigenvalues at each critical point of the Jacobian

- At $(x,y) = (-2,0)$, $\lambda_{1,2}, = i \sqrt{6},-i \sqrt{6}$, trajectories are ellipses.
- At $(x,y) = (0,0)$, $\lambda_{1,2}, =-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}$, trajectories are a saddle point.
- At $(x,y) = (1,0)$, $\lambda_{1,2}, = i \sqrt{3},-i \sqrt{3}$, trajectories are ellipses.

That is enough to give a rough idea of what the phase portrait looks like.

Here are some notes to draw the [*phase portrait by hand*](https://www.math.unl.edu/%7Embrittenham2/classwk/221f09/handouts/linsys) and these [*notes*](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Eisrael/m215/linphase/linphase.html) for stability.

Using this online [*tool*](https://homepages.bluffton.edu/%7Enesterd/apps/slopefields.html), we get the phase portrait (do it by hand using the above)

[image]

Here is the same thing using Mathematica

[image]

Here is a much more detailed phase portrait using Mathematica

[image]